# C# Problem with type cast

Tags: c#, .net

here's the code,

```
Type tbn =   Type.GetType(dii.DictionaryName);
DictionaryXmlInfo4BaseDictionary<tbn>.AddDictionaryXmlInfo((message));//error
```

Comment: What's the error, and what's your question?

Comment: What is the question? What type is message?

Comment: Looks like you are trying to pass a Type as a generic parameter, which isn't supported.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't use generics like that. Generics are meant to be used for types known at *compile time*.

You *can* do it with reflection - getting the generic `DictionaryXmlInfo4BaseDictionary` type definition, creating the closed type using `Type.MakeGenericType`, then calling `AddDictionaryXmlInfo` on it again by reflection... but it's relatively painful.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use generics with a type that is known only at runtime. The `DictionaryXmlInfo4BaseDictionary<T>` type is generic and requires the `T` argument to be known at compile time if you want to use it.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use an instance of a type as a generic parameter.

The generic parameter should be the whatever the base instance is, `DictionaryXmlInfo4BaseDictionary<object>` in the most generic case, but you probably want something further down the class hierarchy than that.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `Type` in that way, refactor `DictionaryXmlInfo4BaseDictionary` so it takes a Type paramater as part of the method e.g.

```
DictionaryXmlInfo4BaseDictionary.AddDictionaryXmlInfo(tbn, message);
```